# npm install is missing modules

Tags: node.js, npm, bower, gulp

Before I can run `gulp` in my project I need to run `npm install`. This works except on my computer, because I get the following error:

```
Error: Cannot find module 'socket.io'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:338:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:280:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:364:17)
    ...
```

I can fix this with

```
$> npm install socket.io
```

Now when I do the install command again I get

```
Error: Cannot find module 'di'
    ...
```

When I install `di` and run the install command again I get:

```
Error: Cannot find module 'log4js'
```

I think that this might continue for a very long time. Any suggestions what is going on here and how to fix this ?

Comment: I have inherited a project where the original author apparently installed all dependencies globally or without `-S` flag. No answer here really answers this question. Is there not a way to automatically install all missing dependencies discovered as imported within the project files on build time by static analysis?

Answer (score 29):

I've faced the same problem when bootstrapping a MEAN application and add each missing dependencie with `npm install packageName --save` was not an option so I came across to [npm-install-missing](https://www.npmjs.com/package/npm-install-missing) whom has saved my life :)

Installation

`npm install -g npm-install-missing`

Usage

```
npm-install-missing
```

Comment: When I try this It tells me that I have no missing modules, although when I run npm list It is loaded with missing and unmet dependencies.

Comment: For me this also says it is finished but does nothing sadly!

Comment: This just goes through `package.json` in each dependency. I need to install dependencies, which are used in project, but somehow forgotten to install.

Comment: Getting UnauthorizedAccess. This is why I hate these pesky platforms with 9000 dependencies, in which 75% are outdated. Just stick to C++.

Answer (score 18):

Running `npm install` will install all dependencies that are specified in the `package.json`. Seems like you have quite a few dependencies that are not defined that way. Use `npm install packageName --save` and npm will add the package to your `package.json`.

Comment: I have about 50 packages in my package.json file. As far as I know, the dependencies of these packages are handled by the package.json of these packages!

Comment: @JeanlucaScaljeri Yes they are. Do you use the latest version of Node & npm?

Comment: This answer is not a solution. some missing module are dependencies of other module. npm: 2.15.1 have the same issue.

Comment: Since 2017 `--save` is not needed.

Answer (score 8):

I am using the same version of npm/node. Sometimes, it is like npm is "lost". What I suggest is :

- rm of your node modules (at least the one that is concerned)
- npm cache clean
- run "npm install" several times, until all dependencies are resolved and no message are displayed

Comment: When you use `npm cache clean` it now says use `npm cache verify` instead, and both commands say you have to use the `--force` flag.

Answer (score 3):

It seems that gulp need 'karma' dependencies (`socket.io ,di ,log4js`...) so you will have to run :

`npm install karma`

so just runing this command solved the problem, and all should be good, the same thing happens with grunt as well for some reasons.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me. By commenting 3 lines in C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\graceful-fs\polyfills.js.

Refer [https://flaviocopes.com/cb-apply-not-a-function/]

```
// fs.stat = statFix(fs.stat) # Line: 61
// fs.fstat = statFix(fs.fstat) # Line: 62
// fs.lstat = statFix(fs.lstat) # Line: 63
```

Answer (score 0):

Beside other answers, if you are using Angular and cannot make new angular project and hangs, you can get into the folder and open terminal and write:

```
npm -i
```

Maybe useful for other things too!!

Comment: I think it wouldn't need the dash(-) before i, !!

Answer (score 0):

I think the npm module [madge](https://www.npmjs.com/package/madge) would help you find the missing dependencies.  It goes through your actual code and makes a list of all the dependencies found within.  You could then do an `npm i` for each of the modules found.

Answer (score 0):

Upgrade your npm version
Install nvm which is easier to switch node js versions
For me node 12.18.3 worked
Just do: nvm use 12.18.3 to switch version

run npm install again and node_modules will appear

Answer (score -1):

If the `npm-install-missing` does not work for you, knowing the name of the Packages that are missing will help you out here. All I had to do was first open my *package.json* file inside VSCode, then paste or type the names of the missing modules into it (under dependencies) according to the way other package names were written there.
Then I ran *npm install* after that.
This method is helpful when you are working on a file but somehow you did not get the package.json file or some of the modules are not listed therein.

Remember to stop and restart a running server after you do npm install for your new dependencies to reflect on your work.

Answer (score -3):

To resolve missing npm modules run:

```
sudo npm install -g npm-install-missing
```

Comment: This answer was already provided in 2015.  If you agree that using the `npm-install-missing` package answers the original poster's question, then give the answer a thumbs up.  If you want to say something to clarify the answer, leave a comment under the answer, but don't create a new one.

Comment: It is 8 years old one, does not work in latest node