# Error: missing script: start when running npm start

Tags: python, reactjs, npm

I'm trying to install & start npm in my mac terminal and I got this error.

I'm not sure what's the problem, I downloaded `npm`, `python3`, `pip`, but it still complaining.

Does any expert have an answer to this?

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [npm start - script not found ?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52068037/npm-start-script-not-found). in other words - do you have a start property in your scripts section of your package.json? if not npm start is not going to work

Comment: Or maybe this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24652681/npm-install-is-missing-modules

Answer (score 0):

1) go project directory 
2) open package.json 
3) you can see scripts key, change the script key like this "start":"which command you want to execute"

Example

```
"scripts": {
    "start": "node index.js" or "nodemon index.js" // which file you wants to run 
  }
```

if package.json not found in your project directory means, run `npm init` inside your project directory